# Inserir dado em uma tabela Pivo Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-5.5

Tenho um relacionamento de muitos para muitos entre itens e area, como faço para relacionar os dois dentro da minha table item_area no meu método store?

Esse é minha view

```
<h3>Criar um novo Item</h3>
<form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="#">
    <label for="name">Nome</label><br>
    <input type="text" name="name"><br>
    <label for="area-select">Selecione a Area</label><br>
    <select name="area-select">
        @forelse ($areas as $area)
            <option value="{{ $area->id }}">{{$area->name}}</option>
        @empty
            <option>Nenhuma Area a ser selecionada</option>
        @endforelse
    </select>
    <br><br>    
    <button type="submit">Cadastrar Produto</button>
</form>
```

Esse é meu método create

```
public function create()
{
    $areas = Area::all();

    return view('item.create')->with('areas', $areas);
}
```

Minha duvida é como recuperar o id da area na rota e como relacionar ambos no método store que vai guardar ambos dentro do banco de dados?

Ficaria algo assim?

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $select_area = $request->input('id');
    $item->area = $select_area;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Para recuperar o ultimo id salvo use DB::getPDO()->LastInsertId();

Comment: Coloque os dois models na sua pergunta e coloque também toda view